# How To Train A Model Using ARIMA In Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, error-handling, statsmodels

I am attempting to train a model surrounding five data points (I know this isn't much but it is all I have at the moment). I'm following a tutorial and everything is going well except I reached a point where the code hits and error and I don't know how to fix it.

```
from statsmodels.tsa.arima.model import ARIMA
print(df.shape)
train = df.iloc[:-30]
test = df.iloc[-30:]
print(train.shape,test.shape)

model = ARIMA(train['Units'],order=(1,0,0))
model_fit = model.fit()
model_fit.summary()
```

The error is a ValueError and it points to the "model = ARIMA(train['Units'],order(1,0,0))". The error reads: "zero-size array to reduction operation maximum which has no identity".
Does anyone know how I can fix this?

As mentioned in the question, I have attempted to resolve this error but I have only a basic understanding of these concepts and I'm not sure how to get rid of it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The error `zero-size array to reduction operation maximum which has no identity`  occurs when there is an empty array or a NaN value in the data. Try to fix it this way:

- Check your data for `NaN` values and remove them before fitting the model.
- Check the size of the data that you are using to fit the model. If the data size is too small, the model may not be able to fit properly.

Your code work perfectly:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.tsa.arima.model import ARIMA

df = pd.DataFrame({'Units': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]})

train = df.iloc[:-2]
test = df.iloc[-2:]

print(train.shape, test.shape)

model = ARIMA(train['Units'], order=(1, 0, 0))
model_fit = model.fit()

print(model_fit.summary())
```

Which gives

```
(3, 1) (2, 1)
                               SARIMAX Results                                
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                  Units   No. Observations:                    3
Model:                 ARIMA(1, 0, 0)   Log Likelihood                 -10.556
Date:                Sun, 05 Mar 2023   AIC                             27.113
Time:                        17:56:17   BIC                             24.409
Sample:                             0   HQIC                            21.677
                                  - 3                                         
Covariance Type:                  opg                                         
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const         20.0000      5.254      3.807      0.000       9.703      30.297
ar.L1       6.665e-06    2.6e+05   2.56e-11      1.000   -5.09e+05    5.09e+05
sigma2        66.6669    311.755      0.214      0.831    -544.361     677.695
===================================================================================
Ljung-Box (L1) (Q):                   0.00   Jarque-Bera (JB):                 0.28
Prob(Q):                              1.00   Prob(JB):                         0.87
Heteroskedasticity (H):                nan   Skew:                            -0.00
Prob(H) (two-sided):                   nan   Kurtosis:                         1.50
===================================================================================
```